# How can I put a Class into Scope of a JJS ScriptEngine in Scala

Tags: java, scala, nashorn

I fail to get a `Class` into scope of the `ScriptEngine` while running `nashorn` in scala.

Here is what I try to do:

```
import javax.script.{ScriptEngine, ScriptEngineManager}
case class MyClass(id: Option[String], name: Option[String])

val manager: ScriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager

val engine: ScriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn")

var simpleScript: String = 
         """
         var myClass = new MyClass('myId', 'myName'); print(myClass.id);
         """`

engine.eval(simpleScript)
```

Does anyone know how to initiate `MyClass` from `JavaScript`?

I get the following Exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "MyClass" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1`
```

Comment: What happens if you try and fully qualify your custom class (with package) when instantiating it in javascript?  Also, your custom class takes `Option` values in it's constructor but in javascript you are passing just strings.

Comment: Changing `Option` to `String` did not make a difference.
And what would be the default package to use, if it's in root?

Answer (score 2):

i would assume its would be the same as trying to access java classes, its worth a try

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147187 suggests

```
var MyClass = Java.type("MyClass");
var inst = new MyClass("myId", "myName");
```

Comment: I think that is not necessary, but tried it anyways. Did not work.

Comment: It seems as if you can not use Scala classes in the script. I created a Java class as a workaround. If no better solution or explanation will be given here, I'll except yours as the solution. Thank you!